# Can't add apps to “Files & Folders” under Security & Privacy

Tags: macbook-pro, permission, privacy

Even after unlocking the lock using my password, I cannot add apps in 2 occasions.

First, (first image as well) the +/- button in "Files and Folders" is greyed out.
Second, (second image), in "Full Disk Access", the +/- is NOT greyed out however, when I select an app, it does not gets added into the list.

Crazy things...

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can't reproduce your Full Disk Access issue. The Files and Folders is by design (I think?) - the apps have to have requested access - your ability is to remove that access. What is it you want to change? In other words, is there a question?

Comment: in full-disk Matlab2021 is already added but I cannot add matlab2019b for some reason. I click on + and then I select matlab2019b but it does not get adeed.